# Where do you happen to be?

Tags: meaning, difference

I was reading a book ("The Telephone" by Kornie Chukovsky) and came across the expression "*where do you happen to be?*". Here is the context:

> My telephone rang. 
> A: "Hello, who's speaking?" 
> B: "The Elephant."
>
> A: "Oh, **where do you happen to be?**" 
> B: "Jungle-Town, Camel-Street, 3."
>
> A: "What do you want?" 
> B: "Some chocolate, sweet, to give my sonnie a
>   bit of a treat."

As far as I can understand "*where do you happen to be?*" seems to be something similar to "*where are you?*".
What does "*where do you happen to be?*" really mean?

What's the difference between "*where do you happen to be?*" and "*where are you?*" ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does just mean "Where are you?"

You might ask "Where do you happen to be?" as a tentative and so polite way of asking "where are you?"  Direct questions can seem rude, but rephrasing can make them more polite.

The quoted dialogue is very strange, and surreal.  I can't imagine what "The Elephant" means.  Is it a code name? The questioner jumps from tentative to direct questions.  The answers seem to be rhyming.  This makes me think that this is not meant to be natural speaking, but a piece of poetry. In which case, the reason for the "Where do you happen to be?" might be just because it fits the poetry better.

Comment: It sounds like a children's book to me.

Comment: Perhaps, but one written in verse, in which case the needs of the poetry and rhyme need to be met.

Comment: I wasn't contradicting you. In fact, the book appears to be a translation from the Russian of a children's book in verse. Presumably the slightly odd choice of words is to preserve the metre of the original.

Comment: Yes. The book is a children's book. The dialogue is written in a way that can rhyme.